# What is the best way to create a custom popup interstitial ad?

Tags: objective-c, swift, interstitial

I currently have an app written in objc and swift.

I would like to implement a custom popup interstitial ad that runs for a few seconds and then presents an X to close the popup and continues doing so every couple minutes unless the 
Remove Ad's in-ap purchase has been purchased.

I already have the in-app purchases setup. I would really appreciate the help or a demo/sample would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate controller with an image view which will popup according to the timer set in app delegate. close X should also have a timer

```
 func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    if (!isShowingAd && adTimer != nil) {
        adTimerTimeLeft = adTimer!.fireDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
        adTimer!.invalidate()
    }

    if adUpdateTimer != nil
    {
        adUpdateTimerTimeLeft = 60 * 60 //one hour
        self.adUpdateTimer!.invalidate()
    }
}
```

//setting timer, This way you can set timer

```
var adTimer: NSTimer? 
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.updateAd), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   timer?.fire()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll have to try this and see if it works. I'm not sure how to add a timer so I'll have to look into that.